# PHP onchange=this.form.submit() on dropdown -> First value get lost

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, dropdown

I use Codeigniter Framework and there I use the dorm_dropdown.

```
  <?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wpstatuses, set_value('wptypes'), 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()'); ?>
```

This is my code and when I add the onchange function then the first value of my options get lost. Without onchange everything is working. Why is this so?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you are missing the closing double quote of the onchange event.

try it like this:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wpstatuses, set_value('wptypes'), 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()"'); ?>
```